# Use of begin(), end() for Pointer Array

Tags: c++

I have below code

```
PositionSummary** psArray_= new PositionSummary*[instSize]
for (int k = 0; k < instSize_; k++)
{
    PositionSummary* ps = new PositionSummary();
    psArray_[k] = ps;

}
```

when I try to do a copy as below, it doesn't work out

```
std::copy(begin(psArray_),end(psArray_),std::back_inserter(psContainer_));
```

Compiler reports "no matching function for call to ‘begin(PositionSummary*&)", how to get around this?

Comment: std::copy(begin(psArray_),end(psArray_),std::back_inserter(psContainer_));___ it is here ah...I missed a "*" here, and I added now...

Comment: It should be `std::begin` and `std::end` unless you have overloads for `begin` and `end` that will be found by ADL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't work because psArray_ is not an array at all, it is a pointer. *You* may know that it points to an array of a specific size, but the compiler has no (general) way of knowing this. If you were to make it an array it would work fine. Try to declare psArray_ like this:

```
PositionSummary* psArray_ [instSize];
```

This will work, but presumably not for you because I'm guessing instSize is not a compile time constant. You can fix that by using a vector instead of doing your own memory allocation:

```
std::vector<PositionSummary*> psArray_;
for (int k = 0; k < instSize; k++) 
    psArray_.push_back (new PositionSummary());

std::copy(psArray_.begin()),psArray_.end(),std::back_inserter(psContainer_));
```

For further improvement, you could consider using a smartpointer in the vector (so you don't have to worry about freeing later). And while I have no idea of the greater context of your code, I'm still wondering why the copy is necessary at all - why not just construct your vector directly in the data structure that is ultimately supposed to hold it?

Answer (score 1):

`psArray` is just a pointer. `std::begin` and `std::end` cannot possibly know the length of the array the pointer points to. They work for plain arrays, not for pointers to arrays.

You can do this instead:

```
std::copy(psArray_, psArray_ + instSize, std::back_inserter(psContainer_));
```

assuming `psContainer_` is a container holding pointers to `PositionSummary`.

Depending on the details of your application, you may be better off using an `std::vector`, either of smart pointers or values:

```
std::vector<some_smart_pointer<PositionSummary>> psArray_;
```

or

```
std::vector<PositionSummary> psArray_;
```

where the second option may be the better one if you don't need referential semantics.